# how to calculate a Mobilenet FLOPs in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, flops

```python
run_meta = tf.RunMetadata()
enter codwith tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
K.set_session(sess)


with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    base_model = MobileNet(alpha=1, weights=None, input_tensor=tf.placeholder('float32', shape=(1,224,224,3)))




opts = tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()    
flops = tf.profiler.profile(sess.graph, run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)

opts = tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.trainable_variables_parameter()    
params = tf.profiler.profile(sess.graph, run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)

print("{:,} --- {:,}".format(flops.total_float_ops, params.total_parameters))
```

When I run above code, I got a below result

```python
1,137,481,704 --- 4,253,864
```

This is different from the flops described in the paper.

mobilenet: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04861.pdf

ShuffleNet: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.01083.pdf

How to calculate exact flops described in the paper?

Comment: You can use following pip package to get some basic information like model's memory requirement, no. of parameters, flops etc. https://pypi.org/project/model-profiler

Answer (score 18):

***tl;dr** You've actually got the right answer! You are simply comparing flops with multiply accumulates (from the paper) and therefore need to divide by two.*

If you're using Keras, then the code you listed is slightly over-complicating things...

Let `model` be any compiled Keras model. We can arrive at the flops of the model with the following code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.backend as K


def get_flops():
    run_meta = tf.RunMetadata()
    opts = tf.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()

    # We use the Keras session graph in the call to the profiler.
    flops = tf.profiler.profile(graph=K.get_session().graph,
                                run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)

    return flops.total_float_ops  # Prints the "flops" of the model.


# .... Define your model here ....
# You need to have compiled your model before calling this.
print(get_flops())
```

However, when I look at my own example *(not Mobilenet)* that I did on my computer, the printed out **total_float_ops was 2115** and I had the following results when I simply printed the `flops` variable:

```
[...]
Mul                      1.06k float_ops (100.00%, 49.98%)
Add                      1.06k float_ops (50.02%, 49.93%)
Sub                          2 float_ops (0.09%, 0.09%)
```

It's pretty clear that the `total_float_ops` property takes into consideration multiplication, addition and subtraction.

I then looked back at the MobileNets example, looking through the paper briefly, I found the implementation of MobileNet that is the default Keras  implementation based on the number of parameters:

[image]

The first model in the table matches the result you have (4,253,864) and the Mult-Adds are approximately half of the `flops` result that you have. Therefore you have the correct answer, it's just you were mistaking flops for Mult-Adds (aka multiply accumulates or MACs).

If you want to compute the number of MACs you simply have to divide the result from the above code by two.

---

**Important Notes**

Keep the following in mind if you are trying to run the code sample:

1. The **code sample** was written in 2018 and doesn't work with tensorflow version 2. See @driedler 's answer for a complete example of tensorflow version 2 compatibility.
2. The **code sample** was originally meant to be run once on a compiled model... For a better example of using this in a way that does not have side effects (and can therefore be run multiple times on the same model), see @ch271828n 's answer.

Comment: why do you need `model` as an argument for  `get_flops`?

Comment: On Tensorflow 2.1.0 it gives an error: `AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'RunMetadata'`

Comment: Number of MACs are not equal to `parameters/2 `. In the paper, you can see `parameters` are 4.2 Million and `Mult-Adds` are 569 Million. So this approach is wrong to calculate number of MACs. I am not sure about the right one too.

Comment: @gizzmole ...idk, lol. Maybe my original line of reasoning was that it has to be a compiled model when you call the function?

@QinHeyang it's totally possible that they deprecated or deleted the module. In fact just browsing the docs and it's in `tf.compat.v1.RunMetadata` in `2.1.0`. Maybe there is a better alternative in the v2 documentation... If you find something I can edit my answer or you can answer it separately.

@AwaisHussain it's not `parameters / 2`, if you re-read my response you'll see I don't claim that.

Answer (score 9):

This is working for me in TF-2.1:

```
def get_flops(model_h5_path):
    session = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()


    with graph.as_default():
        with session.as_default():
            model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_h5_path)

            run_meta = tf.compat.v1.RunMetadata()
            opts = tf.compat.v1.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()

            # Optional: save printed results to file
            # flops_log_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'tf_flops_log.txt')
            # opts['output'] = 'file:outfile={}'.format(flops_log_path)

            # We use the Keras session graph in the call to the profiler.
            flops = tf.compat.v1.profiler.profile(graph=graph,
                                                  run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)

            return flops.total_float_ops
```

Comment: Thanks for your modification, when I run it on a model which has around 18 convolution layers, I get the following ==================Model Analysis Report======================

Profile:
_TFProfRoot                  0 float_ops (0.00%, 0.00%)

======================End of Report========================== something doesn't seem to right. my model summary prints Total params: 176,240
Trainable params: 176,240
Non-trainable params: 0

Comment: I am not sure. Perhaps an issue with the TF 1.x profiler? Note that supposedly they're working on a TF 2.x profiler: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32809

Comment: I got it working, the issue is I was trying to pass the model on the fly after it was generated and compiled. However this code works only if the model  is saved to file and then reloaded.

Comment: Hi, it seems that **this cannot be run twice, otherwise the flops will accumulate**... I have provided a little improvement, see my answer :)

Comment: This does not produce the correct results; it's printing something a lot smaller than the actual FLOPS.

Answer (score 8):

The above solutions *cannot be run twice*, otherwise the flops will **accumulate**! (In other words, the second time you run it, you will get output = flops_of_1st_call + flops_of_2nd_call.) The following code calls `reset_default_graph` to avoid this.

```py
def get_flops():
    session = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()

    with graph.as_default():
        with session.as_default():
            model = keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet(
                    alpha=1, weights=None, input_tensor=tf.compat.v1.placeholder('float32', shape=(1, 224, 224, 3)))

            run_meta = tf.compat.v1.RunMetadata()
            opts = tf.compat.v1.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()

            # Optional: save printed results to file
            # flops_log_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'tf_flops_log.txt')
            # opts['output'] = 'file:outfile={}'.format(flops_log_path)

            # We use the Keras session graph in the call to the profiler.
            flops = tf.compat.v1.profiler.profile(graph=graph,
                                                  run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)

    tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()

    return flops.total_float_ops
```

Modified from @driedler, thanks!

Comment: Can you add the part where you are getting `U.TimingManager` too?

Comment: @JashShah That is nothing but timing how long does the line execute. So I remove it (safely).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. 
Is there a relationship between the input shape and the total flops number? When I changed the input shape, I get the same flops.

Comment: @asendjasni I guess there should. Maybe ask a separate question for your observation?

Comment: Btw, could you explain what the meaning of this output `6.95m float_ops (100.00%, 98.81%)`? Thanks.

Comment: This does not produce the correct results; it's printing something a lot smaller than the actual FLOPS.

Comment: @asendjasni I think it's 
6.95m float ops <total number> (100.0% [accumulated percent of FLOPS], 98.81% [percent of total flops]...

You can see it better with the following sample:
[...]
Mul                      1.06k float_ops (100.00%, 49.98%)
Add                      1.06k float_ops (50.02%, 49.93%)
Sub                          2 float_ops (0.09%, 0.09%)

The bottom row has 0.09 in both sections of the parentheses, and the first value in the tupel increases row over row, accumulating what is below it.

Comment: @buped82 it's hard to know what to respond with without any clarification... this module is pretty lightly documented even in the core tensorflow library: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/profiler/profile

You might have better luck opening an issue in the tensorflow repo if you suspect a bug?

Comment: @Malcolm thank you for the clarification. I may have a related question. I'm trying to calculate the # of FLOPs and the number of parameters, it appears that they also the same with a small margin. Do you have an idea why ? Besides, in many references, they use **G** as the unit of FLOPs, so why here I see an **M**?

Comment: @asendjasni I recommend you ask a separate question on stack overflow for the number of FLOPs vs number of parameters, as it is unclear what information you are missing, or what your question really is... this is also getting pretty off topic from the original question.

The `G` vs the `M` is just the metric prefixes Mega vs Giga: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I'm using 2.8.0 with GPU support. 

`tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_cudamallocasync_allocator.cc:390] Trying to set the stream twice. This isn't supported. 
Aborted (core dumped)`

Answer (score -14):

You can use `model.summary()` on all Keras models  to get number of FLOPS.

Comment: this lists only the number of parameters