# FLOP count for a keras model in python

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, flops

How to get the number of floating-point operations performed by a Keras model in python?

Model.summary() only provides the number of trainable and non-trainable parameters. Can anyone plz tell me how to get the flop count for a keras model?

My model definition is:

***model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=train.shape[1], activation='relu'))***

***model.add(Dense(len(label_list), activation='softmax'))***

for me,

train_shape[1] = 128
label_list = 60

Comment: Does this answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49525776/how-to-calculate-a-mobilenet-flops-in-keras

Comment: @avejidah, thanks for the reply. I have already tried this. But giving me the error of keras.backend has no attribute called get_session.  Plz let me know if there exist any other methods.