# Mismatch in counting operations in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

2 approaches of counting operations in Tensorflow provides different answers. It is not clear how it is counted. Any one can explain this?

I tried below 2 approaches (get_flops, get_flops_tfv2_1) . I didn't expect 2 approaches of profiling to provide different numbers.
get_flops_tfv2_1 provides output as 1440 (close to theoretical operations)
get_flops provides output as 120

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv1D, GlobalAveragePooling1D

def model_gen(win_size, n_feats):
    input1 = Input(shape=(win_size,n_feats), name='input')
    x = Conv1D(filters=120,kernel_size=1,dilation_rate=1, strides=1, padding='same')(input1)
    x13=GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
    model = Model(inputs=input1, outputs=x13)
    return model

def get_flops(model_h5_path):               # https://stackoverflow.com/a/59862883
    tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
    session = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
    with graph.as_default():
        with session.as_default():
            model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_h5_path)
            run_meta = tf.compat.v1.RunMetadata()
            opts = tf.compat.v1.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()
            # We use the Keras session graph in the call to the profiler.
            flops = tf.compat.v1.profiler.profile(graph=graph, run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)
    tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
    return flops.total_float_ops

def get_flops_tfv2_1(model_h5_path):                    # https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32809#issuecomment-1065141109
    from tensorflow.python.profiler.option_builder import ProfileOptionBuilder
    from tensorflow.python.profiler.model_analyzer import profile
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_h5_path)
    forward_pass = tf.function(model.call,
                        input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=(1,) + model.input_shape[1:])])
    graph_info = profile(forward_pass.get_concrete_function().graph,
                            options=ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation())
    # The //2 is necessary since `profile` counts multiply and accumulate
    # as two flops, here we report the total number of multiply accumulate ops
    flops = graph_info.total_float_ops // 2
    return flops

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dur = 6
    model_file = 'tmp.h5'
    
    n_feats=1
    model=model_gen(dur, n_feats)
    model.save(model_file)
    ops = get_flops(model_file)
    # ops = get_flops_tfv2_1(model_file)

    print(f'#Operations = {ops}')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are gonna be different because they use complete different counting methods to measure the operations.

Your first approach `get_flops()` counts the number of floating-point operations in a TensorFlow graph, this method doesn't count operations that do not involve floating-point arithmetic, such as data transfers and memory allocations.

Your second approach `get_flops_tfv2_1()` would count the all MAC operations, that's why the result is different from the first approach.

So the second approach should give you a more accurate estimate, but it may also include some operations that are not relevant to the actual computation.

Comment: Thanks, that was my guess too. 1) get_flops does not count data transfers and get_flops_tfv2_1 will not consider optimizations/actual computations. Is there any method to get actual and all computations which happen on device? 2) Can you please provide references for your answer if available?